# how to buy/sell bsc tokens on pancakeswap from a solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, pancakeswap

I just start to learn solidity and I've finished a couple courses and I want some help to create my first working smart contract.

The smart contract I want to build  will buy and sell tokens on the pancakeswap platform from a smart contract; it like my smart contract will start interacting with a pancakeswap contract to execute some trades, doing the same stuff as I'm  using  their website.

Any help will be appreciated

I have tried to add the interfaces I need to start the interaction between my contract and pancakeswap router contract to use the function

Comment: So you want a bot?

Comment: not exactly, but something similar

Comment: but you need to trigger the smart contract externally, smart contracts are not designed to work that way

Comment: may be but I think of sending some bnb to the smart contract first and then conduct the trades automatically  is this gonna help, I guess in flash loans they do something similar